# Apache Ignite Fault Tolerance Cluster Set up

Tags: ignite

I have started work on Apache Ignite, 
I referred https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs ,but could not understand about cluster.

Is cluster only for data backup?

1.(Node1 client) I created spring rest app and pushing data into cache with

```
      Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml")
      IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache=ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache");

      cache.put(1, "Hello");
      cache.put(2, "World!");
```

2.Reaming Node2,Node3(server) started  with

```
 Ignite ignite = Ignition.start("examples/config/example-ignite.xml"))
```

My question are

1.With these configurations set up to achieve Fault Tolerance?

2.If my Node1 is down ,I have to forward request to another node automatically.

Please help me about cluster configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Ignite cluster is a set of interconnected machines and JVM processes that represented as a single computational unit and storage to your applications.

There are two types of the nodes -  those that store data sets and process your queries and computations (server nodes) and those that you use to connect to the cluster from an application side (client nodes). See more details [here](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/clients-vs-servers).

Answering your questions:

1. To make the cluster fault-tolerant the data redundancy level (number of backup copies of entries) has to be increased as explained [in this doc](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.0/docs/primary-and-backup-copies).
2. No, this is handled automatically by Ignite. You just need to connect to the cluster using a client node and that's it.

Plus, I can suggest you read through the series of Ignite Getting Started Guide:

- [Clustering](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-apachereg-ignite-part-i)
- [Data Grid](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-with-apachereg-ignite-part-2)
- More articles are to be added to the series. Check up the [blogging page periodically](https://ignite.apache.org/blogs.html).